# How to change global state from within a component using useContext? State change not registering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to write an App that allows multiple components to add and remove entries to a set by accessing the global context.

So far I am initialising a Set with useState and feeding the state and the changeState values down to the child components using a context provider, I am then adding and removing items from the Set based on the props passed down into that component.

The code:

The main App file

*/App.js*

```
export const myListContext = createContext(new Set());

function App() {

  const [myList, changeMyList] = useState(() => new Set());

  const Alphabet = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b',
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myList);
  }, [myList]);

  return (
    <myListContext.Provider value={{ myList, changeMyList }}>

      <div className="my-box">
        <Checkbox myEnum={Alphabet.A} title={"Add A to Set"}></Checkbox>
        <Checkbox myEnum={Alphabet.B} title={"Add B to Set"}></Checkbox>

      </div>

    </myListContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

*/Checkbox.js*

```
const Checkbox = ({ myEnum, title }) => {

    const { myList, changeMyList } = useContext(myListContext);

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    function changeIndex() {
        setIndex(index + 1);
        if (index >= 3) {
            setIndex(1);
        }
    }

    function addListItem(item) {
        changeMyList((prev) => new Set(prev).add(item));
    }

    function removeMyListItem(item) {
        changeMyList((prev) => {
            const next = new Set(prev);
            next.delete(item);
            return next;
        });
    }

    function filterItem(item) {
        changeIndex();

        if (index === 0) {
            addListItem(item);
        }

        if (index === 1) {
            removeMyListItem(item);
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="my-checkbox">
            <div
                className="my-checkbox-inner"
                onClick={() => {
                    filterItem(myEnum);
                }}
            ></div>
            <div className="the-title">{title}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The reason for this set up is to Add or Remove Items based on how many times the user has pressed the div, each component needs to track the status of its own index.

Unfortunately, the effect hook on the top layer of the app reports that myList does not contain the new entries.

Why does changeMyList not have a global impact despite change the state via a context.

What am I doing wrong?
console.log(myList) prints (0) depite clicking the buttons that aught to trigger a new entry based on myEnum.

Thanks!

Comment: Typo: changeMyList in the provider value, try using types

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, the typo has been corrected

Answer (score 0):

Set is different than Array and it only contains distinct elements.

**The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references,** according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Therefore, your code already worked. If you console log as `myList.size` will return `2` and `[...myList]` will return an array `["a", "b"]` with an updated values and you can iterate over it to create necessary jsx and etc.

```js
  console.log([...myList]); // ["a", "b"]
  console.log(myList.size); // 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this is true, I have tried to print the alternative statements and they both return 0 despite adding Enums to the set within the respective components.